# Wordpress custom 404 Page

Tags: wordpress

So i am trying to set up custom 404 page. Here is how:

1. i have created 404.php

This works normal. So if user types /blabla in url it gets 404.php content

2. Next i have added in comments "Template Name" at the top of the 404.php file:

```
<?php 
/*
*
*   Template Name: 404 Template
*
*/
?>
```

and in the body i have this code:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>No content found.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

3. In WP Admin at Pages i have created a new page with the name "Error 404" and added some content and choose Template: "404 Template" in dropdown.
   So now if i type in url /blabla which does not exist .. i get 404.php but i dont get content from my "Error 404".

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

4. If i change the name of the file to mytest.php than it works. But that doesnt help coz i need 404.php

I expect that i would get the content from "Error 404" Page which i have created in my WP Admin under Pages.

What i am doing wrong any how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this link will help you :
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/404-pages/

You can add **get_header()** and **get_footer()**, but on 404 page if you read on the link above the hierarchy wordpress doesn't include **the_content()**, cause the 404 page is indicated the page doesn't exist, included the content too.

Comment: i already have get_header() and get_footer() in the file.